# Secondary SQLITE sort order directive seems to be ignored

Tags: android, ios, sqlite

I have an app that's out for both Android and iOS.  There is a lot of complicated SQL queries, so I have a c++ layer that generates the queries so that that logic can be used across both android and ios.

Everything works great, but I noticed that on Android, the secondary sort does not work for me for some reason.

I have a list of items that I want to sort by date, and then secondarily by title.  On iOS, this works fine, on Android, though sorted by date, the titles are not secondarily sorted by title.

The query and database file is the same in both platforms.  The only difference is that I'm using Android's SQLite wrapper instead of the raw C one like on iOS.

For posterity, here is the query:

"SELECT games.gameID, releaseDateInt FROM games WHERE releaseDateInt <= 1542406864 AND releaseDateInt >= 1538778064 ORDER BY releaseDateInt DESC, games.title COLLATE NOCASE ASC"

Again, works fine on iOS, but secondary sort order is ignored on Android.  No warnings on the query execution either.

Any help??

Answer (score 0):

After testing on a few more devices, I've come to the conclusion that this is an Android issue.  It mostly only happens on devices, but never on emulator.  This leads me to believe the sqlite library version on some devices is somehow to blame.